# Easiest way in R to get vector of frequencies of elements in vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of values v. What is the easiest way to get a vector f of length equal to v, where the ith element of f is the frequency of the ith element of v in v?

The only way I know to do it seems unnecessarily complicated:

```
v = sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE)
D = data.frame( idx=1:length(v), v=v )
E = merge( D, data.frame(table(v)) )
E = E[ with(E,order(idx)), ]
f = E$Freq
```

Surely there's a simpler way to do this, along the lines of "frequencies(v)"?

Answer (score 2):

For a vector of small positive integers `v`, as in the question, the expression

```
tabulate(v)[v]
```

is particularly simple as well as speedy.

For more general numerical vectors `v` you can persuade `ecdf` to help you out, as in

```
w <- sapply(v, ecdf(v)) * length(v)
tabulate(w)[w]
```

It's probably better to do the coding of the underlying algorithm yourself, though--and it certainly avoids the floating point rounding error implicit in the preceding solution:

```
frequencies <- function(x) {
  i <- order(x)
  v <- x[i]
  w <- cumsum(c(TRUE, v[-1] != v[-length(x)]))
  f <- tabulate(w)[w]
  return(f[order(i)])
}
```

This algorithm sorts the data, assigns sequential identifiers 1, 2, 3, ... to the values as it encounters them (by summing a binary indicator of when the values change), uses the preceding `tabulate()[]` trick to obtain the frequencies efficiently, and then unsorts the results to make the output match the input, component by component.

Comment: I believe this approach is the most appropriate. Also, in non integer `v`, you could feed `tabulate` with `w = match(v, unique(v))`

Comment: @alexis Thank you for that suggestion.  It leads to a clear and understandable solution.  Although I haven't tested it, I suspect using `match` and `unique` might appreciably slow things down.

Comment: Testing just the `order` and `[` part of your `frequencies` (i.e. the first 2 lines) with `match`: `x = runif(1e5); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x[order(x)], match(x, unique(x)), times = 30)`; `match` seems, already, faster.

Comment: @alexis Very interesting! I'll pay more attention to `match` in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution here is:

```
ave(v,v,FUN=length)
```

It is simply [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html)'s design to replicate and map the return value of `FUN()` back to every index of the input vector whose element was part of the group for which that particular invocation of `FUN()` was performed.

Comment: +1, because I was unaware of `ave`: thank you!  It is syntactically simple and fairly clear.  If performance is an issue, though, it turns out that `ave` takes about twice as long as the `frequency` function in my answer (except for very large vectors, of lengths greater than 100M or so, having very small mean frequencies: `ave` scales better in the small mean frequency case).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works for me:

```
sapply(v, function(elmt, vec) sum(vec == elmt), vec=v)
```

Comment: I think you don't even need to supply the `vec` separately. I.e. simply `sapply( v, function(x) { sum( x==v ) } )` also works for me.

Comment: You're right, I just don't like having global variables in my functions ;)

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's the better coding practice, I think it too :)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use table and as.vector:

```
as.vector(table(dataInVector))
```